# Unable to connect to remote Database using SSH tunneling from a Docker Container

Tags: python, docker, ssh, cx-oracle, ssh-tunnel

My script was running completely fine in my localhost until I started running it inside a Docker Container. I do not know what went wrong. I get **INFO:     Connection to DB failed! due to Exception: No password or public key available!** error

My db_config.py file :

```
with SSHTunnelForwarder(
                (<Bastian Host IP>, 22),
                ssh_username=<user>,
                ssh_pkey='oalkey.openssh',
                ssh_private_key_password=<pass>,
                remote_bind_address=(<Remote DB IP>, 1521),
                local_bind_address=('localhost', 1521)
         ) as tunnel:
            dsn_tns = 

cx_Oracle.makedsn(os.getenv("LOCAL_BIND_HOST",'localhost'),os.getenv("SSH_TUNNEL_PORT",1521),
                                        service_name=os.getenv("OCI_DSP_SERVICE","default"))
            self.db_connection = cx_Oracle.connect(os.getenv("OCI_DAS_NAME"),
                                                   os.getenv("OCI_DAS_PASS"), dsn_tns)
            logger.info('Connection to  DB successful')
        #server.stop()
    except Exception as ex:
        logger.info('Connection to DB failed! due to Exception: {}'.format(ex))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, i fixed the issue. It was because the WORKDIR in my Dockerfile was pointing to the root location and I had to write the relative path in the  ssh_pkey='oalkey.openssh' to ssh_pkey='app/var/www/oalkey.openssh'. Simple :-)